# cin strings into a vector and quicksort them

Tags: c++, string, quicksort, stdvector

> Write a void function called **string_list_sort()** that reads in any number of strings (duplicates are allowed) from **cin**, stores them in a **vector**, and then sorts them. **Don’t use** the standard C++ sort function here — use the version of quicksort that you created.

My problem is I tried to use `strcmp()` but I got a lot of errors, so I tried this method, but I have a problem with `char val = v[end]`. I am not sure how to compare two `std::string` values.
***I changed char to string and it works. Now my problem is for example v = {" apple", "car", "fox", " soap", "foz"}; the result I get is apple, soap, car, fox, foz which is not in alphabetical order***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include "error.h"

using namespace std;

void string_list_sort(vector<string> v){
  string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)){
        if (line.empty()){
            break; 
         }  
       v.push_back(line); 
    }
}

int partition(vector<string>&v, int begin, int end)
{
    char val = v[end];
    char temp;

    int j = end;
    int i = begin - 1;

    while (true)
    {
        while (v[++i] < val)
        while (v[--j] > val)
        {
            if (j == begin)
                break;
        }

        if (i >= j)
            break;

        temp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[j];
        v[j] = temp;
    }

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[end];
    v[end] = temp;

    return i;
}

void quicksort(vector<string>& v, int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin < end)
    {
        int p = partition(v, begin, end);
        quicksort(v, begin, p - 1);
        quicksort(v, p + 1, end);
    }
}
void quick_sort(vector<string>& v)
{
    quicksort(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    v =
    {   " this is a test string,.,!"};
    string word;
    while (cin >> word)
    {
        v.push_back(word);
    }
    quick_sort(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using `std::string`, you can compare with `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`. You don't need to use `strcmp()`. This is the old-fashioned way inherited from C.

Comment: Also, you need to check your keyboard. Your `Tab` key appears to be broken, and as a result the shown code is mostly unreadable.

Comment: Us anonymous users gotta look after one another so I indentorated your code.

Comment: `v` is a `vector<string>`, so what does `v[N]` return?

Comment: @kfsone it should return the first string in the vector if it is lets say V[0] , right? I am confused about should I compare strings in a vector or should I compare each char for each string in the vector?

Comment: @user3328381 Your code says `char val = v[end];`, but you just observed that `v[N]` returns a `string`, not `char`. Once you have the correct type, you can use the string-object's [`compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) member function to do your comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP almost has a sorting function. Two mistakes in particular stand out:

```
char val = v[end];
char temp;
```

`v` is a `vector<string>` so `v[end]` will return a `string`.

```
string val = v[end];
string temp;
```

Takes care of that and makes the program compile and successfully sort. There is no need to go inside the `string`s to compare character by character. `string` does that work for you.

The second problem: Quicksort's partition function is supposed to look like ([Looting from wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort))

```
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[lo]
    i := lo – 1
    j := hi + 1
    loop forever
        do
            i := i + 1
        while A[i] < pivot

        do
            j := j – 1
        while A[j] > pivot

        if i >= j then
            return j

        swap A[i] with A[j]
```

and OP's partition function has picked up a bunch of extra baggage that needs to be removed to get an optimal mark from their instructor. Take a look at the above pseudo implementation and compare it with yours. You may see the mistakes right way, but if not, stand on the shoulders of giants and translate it into C++ (hints: `:=` is plain old `=` in C++, and you'll need to add some `;`s and braces). Debug the result as required. I won't translate it because that would almost totally defeat the point of the assignment.

Side notes (gathering a few important comments):

When writing a test driver don't take in user input until you know the algorithm works. Start with  preloaded input that is easy to visualize like

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> v{"C","B","A"};
    quick_sort(v);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";

    }
}
```

When the output is "A B C ", change the input to something more complicated, but still easy to visualize

```
vector<string> v{"A","C","Q","B","A"};
```

And when that works go nuts and feed it something nasty. I like the [Major General's Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major-General%27s_Song) from the Pirates of Penzance.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare strings using `std::string::compare()` or relational operators. 
It looks like you've tried using relational operators here, but as @user4581301 pointed out, in `partition()` on the first line, you have

> ```
> char val = v[end];
> ```

However, `v[end]` is of type 'string', not 'char'. If you declare `val` and `temp` as `string` instead of `char`, you can sort them with the relational operators you have, and I think you'll be fine.

`compare()` documentation: fttp://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Relational operators: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. Note here: `char val = v[end];` OP is trying to assign a `string` to a `char`. The rest is comparing `string` to `char`.  think this is just a case of OP using the wrong datatype.

Comment: This is true, I'll add it in.

Comment: Not much point. As soon as you clear up the data type they are in position to inspect their code and find they can sort but haven't really implemented quick sort.

Comment: @user4581301 I changed the char to string and deleted the cin part in the main like you said. Now if I have a vector v = {" apple", "car", "fox", " soap", "foz"} and the result I get is    apple, soap, car, fox, foz. It should be in alphabetical order, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try with simple integers first? That way you can get the sort right, and then you can change it to sort strings. I didn't look very closely, but your `partition()` and its nested `while` loops look wrong to me.

Comment: @user3328381: also, how do you change `begin` and `end`? I guess it should be `(int *begin, int *end)`, so partition can change them.